# How to reset form to last loaded values from another form?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My JSF has two forms.  `Form1` is the main form and it is loaded with existing DB values when the page is loaded.  Occasionally, as defined by the business logic, an update submission of Form1 will trigger a `PrimeFaces` `p:dialog`, which contains `Form2` that collects extra data to complement Form1.  If the user provides data that passes validation, the submit `h:commandButton` in Form2 will invoke a backing bean method that will save the data from both forms.  However, if the user cancels the submit button or just closes the the p:dialog, I would like to roll back the state of the view to the last loaded values from the DB.

I have no preference whether to do it by using the PrimeFaces `RequestContext` from the backing bean in a method that is called by the cancel button or by doing it all in the JSF using either JSF EL or `f:ajax`.  How can this be done?

E.g. RequestContext has a method `reset(Collection<String> expressions)` but I would like to not be specifying each form field to be reset, instead do all of them.

Comment: you can use a remoteCommand and call it from the onHide () dialogue and from the cancel button.

Comment: Like @meyquel said before: you have to reload your form calling to a backbean method. Into the backbean method, I think two ways for doing it:
1) You can reload the form fields getting the data from DB (New access to DB)
2) Using backup fields, in other words, replicate your form fields and use them to reload the principal form fields. (No access to DB)